# Filtering by args in Stored Proc

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2015

I have a problem with my code :P obviously right?! Anyway...here's what it is...I want to have a STORED PROC that takes 3 args (@cat, @cutPrice, @option) and returns multiple results that have a type similar to @cat, and a price that is < or > @cutPrice depending on the @option keyword 'above' or 'below'. The problem is when I execute this...

```
EXEC spBookByPrice  
@cat = 'business', @cutPrice = 0.00, @option = 'above'
```

...I get no results, but @option = ' ' shows all prices. Anyway here's my code....

```
ALTER PROC spBookByPrice
@cat varchar(12), @cutPrice money, @option varchar(5)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
    title AS 'Title:',
    type AS 'Category:',
    price AS 'Price:',
    CASE 
        WHEN price >= @cutPrice THEN 'above'
        WHEN price < @cutPrice THEN 'below'
        --ELSE NULL
    END AS 'Option:'
    FROM dbo.titles
    WHERE 'Option:' LIKE '%' + @option + '%'
    GROUP BY type, title, price
    HAVING type LIKE '%' + @cat + '%'
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need:

```
ALTER PROC spBookByPrice
@cat varchar(12), @cutPrice money, @option varchar(5)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
    title AS [Title:],
    type AS [Category:],
    price AS [Price:],
    CASE 
        WHEN price >= @cutPrice THEN 'above'
        WHEN price < @cutPrice THEN 'below'
        --ELSE NULL
    END AS [Option:]
    FROM dbo.titles
    WHERE (CASE WHEN price >= @cutPrice THEN 'above'
                WHEN price < @cutPrice THEN 'below'
            --ELSE NULL
            END) LIKE '%' + @option + '%'
    GROUP BY type, title, price
    HAVING type LIKE '%' + @cat + '%'
END
```

Comment: I just had to replace the [Option:] alias with the full CASE statement

Comment: @Kyle Exactly.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select title [Title:], type [Category:], price [Price:],
  [Option:] = iif(price >= @cutPrice, 'above', 'below')
from titles
where type like concat('%', @cat, '%') and (@option = ''
   or (@option='below' and price < @cutPrice)
   or (@option='above' and price >= @cutPrice))
```